# Storing methods and functions in an array

Tags: java, android

I dont know if its posible but can I store methods or functions in an array? I know Multi dimensional array now and use it to store many arrays as i want. What i would like to do now is to store the methods or functions I create in a certain class. Because i want to store all of my functions to a certain class then call it if i want using loop. And to make my coding cleaner and easy to understand.
Example:

```
public String[] getDesiredFunction = {getName(),getLastname(),getMiddle()};
for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
    if(i == 1){
        getDesiredFunction[i];
    }
}
```

like that?
Is it posible?

Comment: You may implement it using switch statement. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you want, but can do something similar using an `interface`:

```
interface Function {
    public void run();
}

class GetNameFunction implements Function {
    public void run() {
        //do stuff
    }
}
...
```

And then you can write like this:

```
Function[] functions = {new GetNameFunction()};
    for(int i = 0; i < functions.length; i++){
        functions[i].run();
    }
}
```

Comment: interface? ahm are you talking about the view which for example i will store it in class? hehe

Comment: @thenewbie: I don't understand what you mean here. Using an `interface`, you basically surround your functions with a holder object, which allows you to create an array of those holder objects, as I showed you above.

Comment: Ok i get it.. Im not that good in java but i will definitely study this interface method if thats the solution to my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @thenewbie: I would recommend reading up on this and related topics in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Comment: You basically redefined the Runnable interface here

Comment: In Java 8 or later the interface can be implemented using a lambda expression or a method reference.

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 does not have first-order functions, but you can use a functional object pattern:

```
interface NullaryFunction< B > {
    B f();
}

public class Example {
    private final Map< String, NullaryFunction< String > > mFuncs = new HashMap< String, NullaryFunction< String > >() { {
        put( "getName", fncGetName );
        put( "getLastname", fncGetLastname );
        put( "getMiddle", fncGetMiddle );
    } };
    public String getName() { /* ... */ }
    private NullaryFunction< String > fncGetName = new NullaryFunction< String >() {
        @Override String f() { return getName(); }
    };
    public String getMiddle() { /* ... */ }
    private NullaryFunction< String > fncGetMiddle = new NullaryFunction< String >() {
        @Override String f() { return getMiddle(); }
    };
    public String getLastname() { /* ... */ }
    private NullaryFunction< String > fncGetLastname = new NullaryFunction< String >() {
        @Override String f() { return getLastname(); }
    };

    public String runAFunction( String strName ) {
        return mFuncs.get(strName).f();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is not well suited for your use case. It is possible do with [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).

As a starting point you could look into [the reflection trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) or see the related [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

You can store object instance and method name as string, using reflection can invoke this method like this:

```
public class Test {


public void sayHello(){
    System.out.println("hello");
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    String methodName = "sayHello";
    try {
        Method m = test.getClass().getMethod(methodName, null);
        m.invoke(test, null);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

You need refer java [refection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Comment: you can define the class which have two fields : one is object reference and another is method name, so you can store this class instance in an array.

Comment: Basically because reflection breaks java language idea (safe and simple) and has bad performance. More discussions here http://advint.extrapro.ru/articles/reflection.php

Answer (score -2):

The way you stated in the question won't work. As a alternative you could do it like:

```
public String[] getDesiredFunction = {getName(),getLastname(),getMiddle()};
for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
if(getDesiredFunction[i].equals("getName()")){
     getName();
  }
}
```